# How to open full Media Editor in a frame

Tags: media, editor

I'm oppening media editor with this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var frame;
var id;

// Build the choose from library frame.
$(document).on("click", ".upload_image_button", function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id').replace('_b', '');  

    if ( frame ) {
        frame.open();
        return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    frame = wp.media({
        // Tell the modal to show only images.
        library: {
            type: 'image',
        },
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    frame.on( 'select', function() {
        // Grab the selected attachment.
        attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#' + id).val(attachment.url);
    });

    frame.open();
    });
});
```

How can I change it to get view like wp.media.editor.open() opens?

Or how can I access 'wp.media.editor.on( 'select', function() {..' to grab selection from it?

Comment: What do you mean with "full"?

Comment: With ability edit images in a current frame and with the gallery tab.